Save Test Reports of Dockerized Cypress as Bitbucket Pipeline Artifacts
I got troubles persisting my cypress test results as pipeline artifacts. I can verify, that the folder cypress saves the reports to are correct.
there may be something going wrong with the volume mapping from container to pipeline workspace.
bitbucket yml
pipelines:
  custom:
    e2e:
      - step:
          services:
            - docker
          script:
            - mkdir -p cypress-reports/screenshots cypress-reports/mochawesome-report
            - docker-compose -f docker-compose.e2e.yml up -d
          artifacts:
            - cypress-reports/**

docker compose yml
services:
  cypress:
    build: 
      context: .
    volumes:
      - ./cypress-reports/screenshots:/cypress/screenshots
      - ./cypress-reports/mochawesome-report:/mochawesome-report


Assuming your Dockerfile features a RUN directive with a command that would produce the expected reports in a given time:
I'd bet your problem stems from the -d|--detach flag after the docker compose up command: it will immediately detach the pipeline runner shell from the command and, because it is the last command in your pipeline script, the pipeline step ends much before the background process can finish the artifacts.
I'd suggest you replace the docker compose up --detach by a docker compose run cypress instead, which will unequivocally wait for the command to end.
